# Como importar correctamente la SDK para C# en VisualStudio 2013?

Tags: mercadopago

Estoy tratando de comenzar con la integración de MercadoPago en un proyecto nuevo, pero resulta que luego de hacerlo con Nuget (sin error), luego cada código de ejemplo que pego me lo marca con error, aún haciendo un import MercadoPago; Cual puede ser mi error ?

Sinembargo en PHP no he tenido problemas.

Quisiera saber si al margen de esto alguien me puede ayudar a replicar el siguiente código PHP pero en asp.net c#

```
<?php
require_once ('lib/mercadopago.php');

$mp = new MP('xxxxx', 'xxxxxxx');

$item_descripcion = $_POST['descripcion'];
$item_precio = $_POST['precio'];
$item_cantidad = $_POST['cantidad'];

$preference_data = array(
    "items" => array(
        array(
            "title" => $item_descripcion,
            "quantity" => $item_cantidad,
            "currency_id" => "ARS", // Available currencies at: https://api.mercadopago.com/currencies
            "unit_price" => $item_precio
        )
    )
);

$preference = $mp->create_preference($preference_data);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Pay</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="<?php echo $preference['response']['init_point']; ?>">Pagar</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Desde ya muchas gracias. 
Saludos a todos!!

Comment: Por alguna extraña razón en c# no me llega la url y cuando quiero llamar a preference[response][init_point] me lo trae vacio, mientras que en el ejemplo de PHP funciona bien. Agradezco desde ya a quien pueda arrojarme un poco de luz en esto.

Comment: Estas usando un snippet del SDK anterior 0.x, el que instalas con nuget es la version 1.x

Answer (score 0):

En la SDK que se instala via nuget (1.x) el snippet es algo distinto que a la version anterior, para c# seria:

```
Preference preference = new Preference();

preference.Items.Add(
    new Item()
    {
        Title = "Dummy Item",
        Description = "Multicolor Item",
        Quantity = 1,
        UnitPrice = (Decimal)10.0
    }
);

preference.save();
```